# Building Qt5 Git / Perl - path

Tags: perl, git, qt

I have a little comprehension problem.

In the [Qt Wiki](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git#aea23489ce3aa9b6406ebb28e0cda430) is written that I have to:

> *Hint:* Make sure that Perl is added to the path in front of git since that ships an outdated version (Perl 5.8), which will cause the scripts to fail.

But what does this exactly mean? Does it mean the PATH variable? It contains the following items:

```
C:\Python33\
C:\Perl64\site\bin
C:\Perl64\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86
%SystemRoot%\system32
%SystemRoot%
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Autodesk\Backburner\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\
C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4
```

Can someone tell me how to set the path in front of git? I don't know what that means

Regards

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem unless your perl is outdated. If you are running 5.10 or later, everything should be fine (see `perl -v`).

Comment: I'm running the newest version 5.16 - so that should work :/

Comment: @amon: The problem is that git comes bundled with Perl v5.8, so if your PATH is set so that that version is found first then it makes no difference what other versions you have.

Comment: Borodin is right. By calling perl -v from inside the folder it gives me an older perl version (This is perl, v5.8.8 built for msys)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the command processor doesn't find a program in the current directory, it will check each of the directories in the `PATH` environment variable and execute the first one it finds. What the wiki is saying is that, because the git installation contains an outdated version of Perl, if the git directory appears first in the `PATH` list then it will be chosen instead of any other installed version of Perl.

`git` doesn't appear in your `PATH` so the problem doesn't arise. In any case the entries for `Perl` are right near the beginning of the list, so the installed Perl will be chosen before anything else.

Comment: That were my thoughts also but i get this error:

D:\GitHub> cd qt5
D:\GitHub\qt5 [stable]> perl init-repository
"GetOptionsFromArray" is not exported by the Getopt::Long module
Can't continue after import errors at init-repository line 201
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at init-repository line 201.

Comment: That is a problem with the version of `Getopt::Long`, not with the version of Perl. Make sure by issuing `perl -v` from `D:\GitHub\qt5` and ensure that your version is something better than 5.8. If so then just reinstall `Getopt::Long`.

Comment: You are right. Calling perl -v from the D:\GitHub\qt5 folder gives me: This is perl, v5.8.8 built for msys - By googeling I didn't found anything how to install/update my perl version in Git. Can you tell me what to do?

Comment: Then I would say there must be a `perl.exe` in `D:\GitHub\qt5`? Can you run your command from somewhere else? It may work if you rename the `perl.exe` to something else (I usually add an underscore, so `perl.exe_`)

Comment: Hi, already thank you very much, you are genius. After I renamed the perl.exe from the bin dir, calling -perl -v from the git shell('s) gave me the right (installed) version. But I still have a little problem. Maybe u can help me here also. The wiki tells me, that I'm not able to build Qt5 if sh.exe (Shell) is in my path, but msys and the Git Shell from GitHub both use the sh.exe (and not cmd). Maybe you also have a solution for this problem. Sorry if it's fairly simple, but I'm totally new to this topic. Already best regards!

Comment: If someone else ever has the problem here is a how to now http://www.q-visions.de/tutorial/howto-build-qt5-from-git-for-microsoft-visual-studio-2012

Comment: i have the same problem.."GetOptionsFromArray" is not exported by the Getopt::Long module...how to solve it ? thank you...perl -v display 5.8.8 version. thank you..

Answer (score 5):

I get the same problem, i installed the perl 5.16.3. but the perl -v shows 5.8.8, I looked into the perl's folder and found that there are two .exe files named perl.exe and perl5.16.3.exe. then I typed "perl5.16.3 init-repository", it runs OK!

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
1. Download and install the latest version of ActiveState perl (5.16.3 now)
2. Copy the contents (replacing existing files) of 
C:\Perl 
to 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git 
(yeah, lots of crap but it doesn't matter)
3. Uninstall ActiveState perl

Result: you have an updated version of perl inside git.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest solution:

Assuming that you installed some up-to-date version of Perl and it is already in PATH, simply go to where GIT executables are is, which is normally

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
```

and **rename `perl.exe` to `perl1.exe`**. If you really are so unhappy about this, rename it back after you're done with whatever is getting the problem.

Why does this solve the problem? Because your program will not find perl in GIT's directory, and will try to find it somewhere else, and since your have the latest version of Perl in PATH, it will find it and everything will workout.

PS: It worked with me :-)