# Can't run the standard Hello World Qt Quick 2.0 project on Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 7" with Qt 5.2

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

I just bought a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 7" with Android version 4.1.2. To do a simple test I wanted to run the Qt 5.2, Qt Quick 2.0, "Hello World" application. The program starts, but only a black screen is shown. I also tried the "QuickForecast" from Google Play store and it does not run as well.

The application output is:

```
Starting remote process.D/dalvikvm( 1917): GC_CONCURRENT freed 334K, 17% free 

8624K/10375K, paused 19ms+12ms, total 59ms
D/dalvikvm( 1917): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libgnustl_shared.so 0x41a304c8
D/dalvikvm( 1917): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libgnustl_shared.so 0x41a304c8
D/dalvikvm( 1917): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libgnustl_shared.so 0x41a304c8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1917): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libQt5Core.so 0x41a304c8
D/dalvikvm( 1917): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libQt5Core.so 0x41a304c8
D/dalvikvm( 1917): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libQt5Network.so 0x41a304c8
D/dalvikvm( 1917): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libQt5Network.so 0x41a304c8
I/Qt      ( 1917): Network start
D/dalvikvm( 1917): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libQt5Qml.so 0x41a304c8
D/dalvikvm( 1917): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libQt5Qml.so 0x41a304c8
D/dalvikvm( 1917): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libQt5Qml.so 0x41a304c8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1917): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libQt5Gui.so 0x41a304c8
D/dalvikvm( 1917): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libQt5Gui.so 0x41a304c8
D/dalvikvm( 1917): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libQt5Gui.so 0x41a304c8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1917): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libQt5Quick.so 0x41a304c8
D/dalvikvm( 1917): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libQt5Quick.so 0x41a304c8
D/dalvikvm( 1917): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libQt5Quick.so 0x41a304c8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1917): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so 0x41a304c8
D/dalvikvm( 1917): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so 0x41a304c8
D/dalvikvm( 1917): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so 0x41a304c8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1917): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroidGL.so 0x41a304c8
D/dalvikvm( 1917): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroidGL.so 0x41a304c8
I/Qt      ( 1917): qt start
W/dalvikvm( 1917): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtMessageDialogHelper'
D/dalvikvm( 1917): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so 0x41a304c8
D/dalvikvm( 1917): Shared lib '/data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so' already loaded in same CL 0x41a304c8
D/dalvikvm( 1917): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libAndroidHelloWorld.so 0x41a304c8
D/Qt      ( 1917): qml\qqmlengine.cpp:1451 (QQmlDebuggingEnabler::QQmlDebuggingEnabler(bool)): QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
D/dalvikvm( 1917): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libAndroidHelloWorld.so 0x41a304c8
D/dalvikvm( 1917): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.AndroidHelloWorld/lib/libAndroidHelloWorld.so 0x41a304c8, skipping init
W/Qt      ( 1917): kernel\qcoreapplication.cpp:416 (QCoreApplicationPrivate::QCoreApplicationPrivate(int&, char**, uint)): WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.
D/dalvikvm( 1917): GC_CONCURRENT freed 495K, 19% free 8598K/10503K, paused 3ms+35ms, total 62ms
W/dalvikvm( 1917): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNativeInputConnection'
W/dalvikvm( 1917): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtExtractedText'
D/libEGL  ( 1917): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_MRVL.so
D/libEGL  ( 1917): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_MRVL.so
D/libEGL  ( 1917): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_MRVL.so
D/GC      ( 1917): <tid=2041> OES20 ===> GC Version   : GC Ver-988-JB-R4-RC2-GC19 
D/GC      ( 1917): 
E/libEGL  ( 1917): eglMakeCurrent:538 error 3002 (EGL_BAD_ACCESS)
W/Qt      ( 1917): eglconvenience\qeglplatformcontext.cpp:119 (virtual bool QEGLPlatformContext::makeCurrent(QPlatformSurface*)): QEGLPlatformContext::makeCurrent: eglError: 3002, this: 0x5d2b8d50 
W/Qt      ( 1917): 
E/libEGL  ( 1917): eglMakeCurrent:538 error 3002 (EGL_BAD_ACCESS)
W/Qt      ( 1917): eglconvenience\qeglplatformcontext.cpp:119 (virtual bool QEGLPlatformContext::makeCurrent(QPlatformSurface*)): QEGLPlatformContext::makeCurrent: eglError: 3002, this: 0x5d2b8d50 
W/Qt      ( 1917): 
E/libEGL  ( 1917): eglMakeCurrent:538 error 3002 (EGL_BAD_ACCESS)
W/Qt      ( 1917): eglconvenience\qeglplatformcontext.cpp:119 (virtual bool QEGLPlatformContext::makeCurrent(QPlatformSurface*)): QEGLPlatformContext::makeCurrent: eglError: 3002, this: 0x5d2b8d50 
W/Qt      ( 1917): 
E/libEGL  ( 1917): eglMakeCurrent:538 error 3002 (EGL_BAD_ACCESS)
W/Qt      ( 1917): eglconvenience\qeglplatformcontext.cpp:119 (virtual bool QEGLPlatformContext::makeCurrent(QPlatformSurface*)): QEGLPlatformContext::makeCurrent: eglError: 3002, this: 0x5d2b8d50 
W/Qt      ( 1917): 
W/Qt      ( 1917): ..\src\androidjnimain.cpp:687 (void updateWindow(JNIEnv*, jobject)): updateWindow: Dirty screen not implemented yet on OpenGL
E/libEGL  ( 1917): eglMakeCurrent:538 error 3002 (EGL_BAD_ACCESS)
W/Qt      ( 1917): eglconvenience\qeglplatformcontext.cpp:119 (virtual bool QEGLPlatformContext::makeCurrent(QPlatformSurface*)): QEGLPlatformContext::makeCurrent: eglError: 3002, this: 0x5d2b8d50 
W/Qt      ( 1917): 
E/libEGL  ( 1917): eglMakeCurrent:538 error 3002 (EGL_BAD_ACCESS)
W/Qt      ( 1917): eglconvenience\qeglplatformcontext.cpp:119 (virtual bool QEGLPlatformContext::makeCurrent(QPlatformSurface*)): QEGLPlatformContext::makeCurrent: eglError: 3002, this: 0x5d2b8d50 
W/Qt      ( 1917):
```

I found a bug report on the Qt website:

[Found here](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-34984)

but the problem has not been solved yet and the application output is not identical (but similar) with mine.

Do anyone have a similar problem and been able to solve it? Do anyone have any suggestion on how this might be solved?

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried git stable and/or dev?

Comment: @LaszloPapp: I have only tried the Qt 5.2 release. I tried using new source, but can't get it set up.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by cannot get it set up?

Comment: @LaszloPapp: When running: perl init-repository following this guide: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building-Qt-5-from-Git. I get error (will update with picture in my question above.

Comment: @Phataas, Try googling your problem next time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383300/building-qt5-git-perl-path#comment20016260_14385564

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug fix is now to be resolved and will probably be fixed already in Qt 5.2.1.

Follow [this](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-34984) link for status.